# PHP Regular Expression - Single Quote not working - TWIG pre-escaping

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression, twig

I got a problem with single quotes in a regular expression.
What i want to do is replace smileys in a string to a html image tag.
All smileys are working, except the sad smiley :'-( because it has a single quote in it.
Magic Quotes is turned off (testet with if (g!et_magic_quotes_gpc()) dd('mq off');).

So, let me show you some code.

```
    protected $emoticons = array(
        // ...
        'cry' => array(
            'image' => '<img class="smiley" src="/image/emoticon/cry.gif" />',
            'emoticons' => array(":'(", ";'(", ":'-(", ";'-(")
        ),
    );
```

My method to replace all the emoticons is the following:

```
    public function replaceEmoticons($input) {

        $output = $input;

        foreach ($this->emoticons as $emo_group_name => $emo_group) {

            $regex_emo_part = array();

            foreach ($emo_group['emoticons'] as $emoticon) {
                $regex_emo_part[] = preg_quote($emoticon, '#');
            }

            $regex_emo_part = implode('|', $regex_emo_part);
            $regex = '#(?!<\w)(' . $regex_emo_part .')(?!\w)#';
            $output = preg_replace($regex, $emo_group['image'], $output);

        }

        return $output;

    }
```

But as i said: ' kills it. No replacement there. :-) :-/ and so on are working. Why?
FYI Content of $regex: `#(?!<\w)(\:\'\(|;\'\(|\:\'\-\(|;\'\-\()(?!\w)#`

What is wrong here, can you help me?

UPDATE:

Thanks @ cheery and cychoi. The replacing method is okay, you've got right.
I found the problem. My string gets escaped before it is forwarded to the replaceEmoticons method. I use TWIG templating engine and i use |nl2br filter before my selfmade replace_emoticon filter.
Let me show you. This is the output in the final template. It is a template to show a comment for an blog entry:

```
{{ comment.content|nl2br|replace_emoticons|raw }}
```

Problem: nl2br is auto pre-escaping the input string, so ' gets replaced by the escaped one  &#039;

I need this nl2br to show linebreakes as <br /> - and i need the escaping too, to disallow html tags in the user's input.
I need replace_emoticons to replace my emoticons (selfmade TWIG extension).
And i need raw here at the end of the filter chain too, otherwise all HTML smiley img tags gets escaped and i will see raw html in the comment's text.

What can i do here? The only problem here seems to be that nl2br escapes ' too. This is no bad idea but in my case it will destroy all sad smileyss containing ' in it.

Still searching for a solution to solve this and i hope you can help me.

Best,
titan

Comment: Can you show the input string? May be it does not have quotes, but html entity `&quot;` or some unicode symbol?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any problem: http://3v4l.org/IYOg5

Comment: Thanks! Thank you. You brought me on the right way and I updated my question above.

Comment: @titanbird what happens if you "escape" you emoticons before replacing (eg. `$emoticon = nl2br($emoticon);` just before you `preg_quote` it)

Comment: @iLot, works! I added an optional parameter to the replaceEmoticons method, $encode_emoticons = true. So the emoticons get encoded and the characters get transformed into html signs. I think it is not the best way at all, but it works. Sometimes i want to apply this method to an unescaped input string. But this is okay. In this case i can use replaceEmoticons(false) then. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an optional parameter to the emoticon method:

```
public function replaceEmoticons($input, $use_emo_encoding_for_regex = true) {
```

and i changed the foreach part a lil' bit:

```
foreach ($emo_group['emoticons'] as $emoticon) {

    if ($use_emo_encoding_for_regex === true) {
        $emoticon = htmlspecialchars($emoticon, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    $regex_emo_part[] = preg_quote($emoticon, '#');

}
```

It works! All emoticons are replaced!